# Client Time performance tuning using Glimpse

Tags: asp.net, webforms, glimpse

I am using Glimpse 1.8.6 in an ASP.net Web Forms application in VS2013 deployed to an Azure Website (standard tier).  I have a user control embedded in an aspx page, my question is about the specific timings in the Requests section.

I am typically seeing 3000-4000ms Request times, 5-25ms Wire, 500-1000ms Server and 2000+ Client.  Additionally load is about 500-700ms and render is sub 100ms.

The "Client" portion is my question, what exactly is used to calculate client and more importantly where should I be looking in my code to decrease that number?

Comment: This is a generic asp.net performance question and isn't specific to the Azure platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question... The Client time is the difference between [loadEventEnd](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/#dom-performancenavigationtiming-loadend) and [responseEnd](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/#dom-performancenavigationtiming-responseend) (you can see the relevant code [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Client/blob/master/source/glimpse.hud.js#L152)). In English terms this everything that happens from the time the browser receives last byte from the server (for the main document) to when the `load` event for the current document is run (this typically occurs after all external resources have loaded).

Most of the time, to improve this number, it involves caching aggressively, bundling your documents together, etc. There is a great talk that Nik Molnar did on this which has a fairly large section on optimizing these types of - http://vimeo.com/97415381.